# Python Script to read files from FTP instead from local folder

Tags: python, ftp

I have a working python script that locally reads wav files and extracts each file's properties. I moved all my data to my FTP server and I don't know how to switch the script to read from my FTP server rather than reading from my desktop. Not sure if for the script is important to define the use of port 21 or 22.    Thanks a million

```
import csv
from datetime import timedelta
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
from os.path import getctime, getatime, getmtime
from wavinfo import WavInfoReader
from time import ctime


# OUTPUT FILE HEADERS
EXTRACTED_HEADERS = ['copyright', 'product', 'album', 'genre', 'artist', 'created_date', 'title']
DURATION_HEADER = 'duration'
CREATED_TIME_HEADER = 'created_time'
MODIFIED_TIME_HEADER = 'modified_time'
ACCESS_TIME_HEADER = 'access_time'

# ERROR FILE HEADERS
FILE_NAME_HEADER = 'file_name'
ERROR_HEADER = 'error'


def get_input():
    wav_folder = input('Path to your folder: ').strip()
    while not wav_folder:
        wav_folder = input('Path to your folder is required (Exit by press Ctrl + C): ').strip()
    o_file = input('Path to your output file (default is output.csv):').strip() or 'output.csv'
    e_file = input('Path to your error file (default is error.csv): ').strip() or 'error.csv'
    return wav_folder, o_file, e_file


def write_output_file(output_list, file):
    with open(file, 'w+') as f:
        dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=[FILE_NAME_HEADER] + EXTRACTED_HEADERS + [DURATION_HEADER, CREATED_TIME_HEADER, MODIFIED_TIME_HEADER, ACCESS_TIME_HEADER])
        dict_writer.writeheader()
        for op in output_list:
            dict_writer.writerow(op)


def write_error_file(failure_list, file):
    with open(file, 'w+') as f:
        dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=[FILE_NAME_HEADER, ERROR_HEADER])
        dict_writer.writeheader()
        for fl in failure_list:
            dict_writer.writerow(fl)


def run():
    folder_path, output_file, error_file = get_input()
    only_files = [f for f in listdir(folder_path) if isfile(join(folder_path, f))]
    output = []
    failure = []
    for file_name in only_files:
        # Only parse for wav file
        if not file_name.endswith('wav'):
            continue
        properties = {
            FILE_NAME_HEADER: file_name
        }
        full_path = join(folder_path, file_name)
        try:
            # Parse Wav Info
            w = WavInfoReader(full_path, info_encoding='utf-8', bext_encoding='utf-8')
            info_dict = w.info.to_dict()
            for header in EXTRACTED_HEADERS:
                properties[header] = info_dict.get(header, '')

            # Calculate the length
            properties[DURATION_HEADER] = str(timedelta(seconds=w.data.byte_count / w.fmt.byte_rate))

            # Parse File Info
            properties[CREATED_TIME_HEADER] = ctime(getctime(full_path))
            properties[MODIFIED_TIME_HEADER] = ctime(getmtime(full_path))
            properties[ACCESS_TIME_HEADER] = ctime(getatime(full_path))
            output.append(properties)
        except Exception as e:
            failure.append({
                FILE_NAME_HEADER: file_name,
                ERROR_HEADER: str(e)
            })
    write_output_file(output, output_file)
    write_error_file(failure, error_file)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Comment: The module "ftplib" of standard library provides FTP-client support. Read its docs. If you have a specific issue while solving this yourself you can ask here.

Answer (score 0):

Import these module to your code:

```
import ftputil
import urllib2
import shutil
import urllib.request as request
from contextlib import closing
```

and in run method instead of readind files from disk, download them and do the rest of process:

```
a_host = ftputil.FTPHost(hostname, username,passw)

for (dirname, subdirs, files) in a_host.walk("/"): # directory
    for f in files:
        if f.endswith('wav'):
            a_host.download(f, f)  # Download first
            with open(f) as txtfile:
                content = txtfile.read()
```

Comment: While a code like this will technically work, it will download a complete media file. While the OP seems to want to read just the file header. So it might be quite inefficient. Well, FTP is not ideal storage for this kind of needs.

Comment: Yes, I don't want to download any file

Comment: @hbtousa Well your module which read wave file information (WavInfoReader), just accepts file path from disk to read it. You can not access ftp files in this way. If you don't want to download to disk, you have to find another module that accepts file or stream object instead of file path. This is another solution. I think there won't be another choice.

Comment: @hbtousa May be looking this module for reading wav file info would help, instead of WavInfoReader.